# Frank Jackson's counter argument to material implication

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am reading "On assertion and indicative conditionals" by Frank Jackson and have trouble with the following paragraph:

"The problem for the Equivalence thesis is to explain away the putative counter examples to 'P ⊢ (P → Q)' and 'Q ⊢ (P → Q), the only too familiar cases where despite the high probability of –P or of Q, and so of (P ⊃ Q), (P → Q) is not highly assertable."

I do not understand how 'P ⊢ (P → Q)' could be the case. As far as I know, this '–P ⊢ (P → Q)' is the paradox, with the negation of the antecedent, not without it as Frank states. How can you prove it?

Comment: You have forgotten the negation sign: it is $\lnot P \to (P \to Q)$ and  $Q \to (P \to Q)$.

Comment: That is what I am saying! Maybe the version I have is incorrectly written. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: In the article, there is the negation sign: the putative counter examples to "-P ⊢ (P→Q)" and "Q ⊢ (P → Q),".

Comment: Just checked myself .. the negation symbol is there .... it's just not very big